# Checking for new rows in database - with polling or SQL dependency?

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf

I have a few rows in a database. I have created a windows service which is updating new rows in database after every 5 mins.

Now I want to keep track of new rows, if there are any..... in  WCF service and send a notification to client about it.

Database is SQL Server, polling the database or this SQL dependency what is the way to go? a code snippet would help a lot

Comment: or a trigger on new record inserted...

Comment: @st_stefanov and how would a trigger notify clients exactly??

Comment: Remus, there is a solution for that if his implementation allows it. He can use publish/subscribe MQ Communication solution and send a notification message which is received by all clients and they will execute their logic on this event. We've been using it for years.

Answer (score 1):

For a frequency of updates of 5 min is much better to use Query Notifications (ie. [`SqlDependency`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx)). See [Remove pooling for data changes from a WCF front end](http://rusanu.com/2007/11/01/remove-pooling-for-data-changes-from-a-wcf-front-end/) for an example. If you use LINQ then you can also use [LinqtoCache](http://code.google.com/p/linqtocache/) which offers a SqlDependency backed cache invalidation for LINQ queries.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `date` or `datetime` (depending on your version of SQL Server) field to your table which is the "sent to client" date. Default this to `NULL`.

Write a stored procedure for your service to call which returns a result set of all the rows with a `NULL` date. Within the same procedure set all the NULL dates to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` to mark them as "sent to client"

Poll the procedure as frequently as necessary.

Comment: oh i think i'll go with this sql cache dependency, adding another column in database is not an option..thanks anyways..

Comment: @PiyushSardana - If you have resolved your problem please post it as an answer and accept it. That way you won't have people continue to add answers to this question.

Comment: I didnt resolve it yet, but i found sth, which may help me to implement the same in WCF, here's the link  http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=263

Comment: no luck yet, still cant figure out the way to use sql dependency in wcf srvice

Comment: Can you modify the database in any way? I know you said you could not add a column but how about another table?

Comment: so yes, i can modify my database and i have added a datetime column there